# Elasticsearch : Multiple conditions in query string

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the following JSON for applying multiple conditions in the search query.

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field : "andi_new"
          "query": "network:onenetwork AND publisher:someplublisher"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "time": {
            "gte": "2015-03-12 00:00:00",
            "lte": "2015-03-12 23:59:59"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am selecting the filter values based on a drop down in my PHP web application. So all the filters are not applied once.

If I have only condition in the quesry string query, everything is working fine. Also if i include OR then also it is working. But when I add 'AND' and provide another column condition as shown above, it is not working. Is there any other filter for applying different conditions ?

Comment: what is it returning?

Comment: This is returning me an error "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase"

Comment: can you update with your index mapping? I'm suspicious about andy_now not being a field!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing double inverted quote after `default_field` and a comma at the end of that line. Try the query below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field" : "andi_new",
          "query": "network:onenetwork AND publisher:someplublisher"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "time": {
            "gte": "2015-03-12 00:00:00",
            "lte": "2015-03-12 23:59:59"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still I am getting the same.  My question is is this the right way of quesrying aganist multiple fields ?

Comment: Please mention the entire error message. That should help in narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the right way to use multiple fields inside a `query_string`.